Making :global() CSS Module work with sass-loader
I have this SASS mixin:
@mixin fadeIn($duration) {
  animation-duration: $duration;
  animation-fill-mode: both;

  & :global {
    animation-name: keyframesFadeIn;
  }
}

I'm using :global for animation-name because I want to reuse the keyframes. However, this is causing deprecation warnings:
[0] Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[0] Deprecation Warning on line 155, column 2 of file:///foo.scss:155:2:
[0] Sass's behavior for declarations that appear after nested
[0] rules will be changing to match the behavior specified by CSS in an upcoming
[0] version. To keep the existing behavior, move the declaration above the nested
[0] rule. To opt into the new behavior, wrap the declaration in `& {}`.
[0]
[0] More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/mixed-decls
[0]
[0] 155 |   display: flex;

This is because SASS thinks & :global is a nested style. I also tried doing this:
@mixin fadeIn($duration) {
  animation-duration: $duration;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: :global(keyframesFadeIn);
}

I think it should work, but Webpack is throwing errors:
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Expected expression.
    ╷
151 │   animation-name: :global(keyframesFadeIn);
    │                   ^

Is there a way to reuse global keyframes while also avoiding the deprecation warning?
